# My root domain is not resolving to my server, but the www. subdomain works fine

Tags: dns, cname, no-www

I have the DNS configured like this:

[image]

So, my domain `example.mx` is working as `http://www.example.mx`. With `www` there is no problem, but with non-`www` like `http://example.mx` it's not working.

As you can see, my DNS records are pointing in `example.mx` record to the `NS` `ns1.example.mx`. Actually, `ns1.example.mx` is pointing to my server's IP.

What could be the problem which is causing `http://example.mx` not to work while `http://www.example.mx` does work?

**Update**:

Thank you to all of you for your responses. Unfortunally, I couldn't properly configure the `non-www` entry for my website because I can't allow (as Stephen Ostermiller said) a `CNAME` record, so I'm happy having my `www` entry and I'll stick to working with that.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer, the domain i'm trying to configure it's vueloenglobo.mx which is the domain i can't enter by http://vueloenglobo.mx just it's working on http://www.vueloenglobo.mx, i mean, with www

Answer (score 3):

To resolve your host name to an IP address you need either an `A` or `CNAME` record for it.   For a bare domain, it has to be an `A` record, a `CNAME` only works for sub-domains.  You don't have an `A` record for your bare domain name, you only have `NS` and `SOA` records.

Your CNAME resolves to some IP address.  If you don't know the IP address you can usually look up the IP address for the host of the CNAME and use that.

Sometimes `CNAME` records point to dynamic IP addresses that change fairly frequently.  If that is the case, you will also need to set up the `A` record for your bare domain to get updated at the same time.  Alternatively you can find a DNS host that uses `ALIAS` or `ANAME` records.   Those are proxy records that return an `A` record with an IP address based on a dynamic lookup from some other host.  Not all DNS hosting offers this option (most don't).

You have both `A` and `CNAME` records for `www.`  That isn't usual and it could cause problems.  I don't see any records for the `ns.` subdomain the CNAME is pointing to, so I doubt it is actually functional.

I would recommend:

- Add an `A` record for `example.mx` pointing to your server's IP address
- Remove the `CNAME` record for `www.`

To get your web site working, you may additionally need to configure your web server to show your site for your bare domain.   It isn't always enough just to point a host name at your web server.  You also usually have to add virtual host configuration for it as well.

Comment: Thanks, Stepehn, It's a little complicate to me use an A record because i have dynamic public ip. So, Is there another way to point  `example.mx` to a CNAME or NS insted an A record? This is just for validate an SSL which is asking me to verify my non-www domain. Thanks agian-

Comment: Additional by the way, i'm using CNAME record because i'm pointing my domain `example.com` to there, because as i told you, i don't have an static public ip to use it on `A` record.

Comment: I added info about what to do if you don't know the IP address, or if it is dynamic.

Comment: "I don't see any records for the `ns.` subdomain the CNAME is pointing to" - to add to the confusion, it's actually pointing to `ns1.` on a subtly different domain name which does return a DNS record. There would seem to be two domains referenced in the question: `example.mx` and `exaSmpleS.mx`.

Answer (score 1):

The "A" entry is correct, because you made a CName fowarding entry to the domain vuelosenglobos.mx

Remove the DNS Entry:

```
    vuelosenglobo.mx NS  ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx
```

Add the DNS entry:

```
    vuelosenglobo.mx CNAME  ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx
```

by the way, Its unusual to see ns1 as a web server subdomain, but whatever

name servers are different devices from web servers.

Comment: You can't set a `CNAME` at the domain apex with breaking things.  See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-cant-a-domain-s-root-be-a-cname-8cbab38e5f5c/#cname-limitations  It causes mail delivery failure for the domain among other problems.

Comment: ns1.vuelosenglobos.mx is a sub domain, that is cnamed also, and pointing to a no-ip ddns domain. Hosting is not online, just dns accounts from the path.  @Stephen Ostermiller BTW Im an ISP, and decided what he should do with what he is doing... Of course I could try to sell him some webspace, but decided to give him the real action for what he already paid for.

Comment: He has to have hosting to have e-mail, not just dns accounts.